# In theory, could List<Struct>.GetRange() be as fast as List<List<Struct>>[i]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cpu-cache

I am going to benchmark my particular case, but I want to know the basic argument for or against doing following.

When submitting matrices for geometry instancing, assuming each batch contains a List of positions, where Position is a small Struct, we could:

**(A)** Iterate over a `List<Position>` and a `List<int>`, and use the result of `List<int>[i]` to do `List<Position>.GetRange(offset, count)`, submit to GPU.

**(B)** Iterate over a `List<List<Position>>`, submit `List<List<Position>>[i]` to GPU.

(The assumption is `List<Position>.Count` per batch will be quite small.)

Intuitively, it seems (B) would be faster in terms of CPU caching, is it true in theory?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/